# RecyclerView - Filter items using keyboard like a ListView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, filter

When `Filterable` is implemented in an adapter of a `ListView`, pressing keys in keyboard while the view is active filters the items nicely (with a floating `Filter` widget at the bottom) but doing the same for an adapter of a `RecyclerView` doesn't do anything. The only way to filter items in the latter case is to use alternative methods such as using a `SearchView`. According to various answers given here, `Filter` is a perfectly usable widget for `RecyclerView`.

Filtering items using a keyboard like above is very convenient for users who use Android TV, for example.

PS: I don't think that posting the differences between `ListView` and `RecyclerView` will do any good but I will include the detailed implementation in both ways if requested.

Comment: If you want to filter items in the recycler view, you can simply apply filters on the source list and reset adapter items with the filtered one and then call `notifyDatasetChanged`.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar sorry, this is not what I meant. I know how to filter items. It's about a particular feature that seems to be missing in `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding TextWatcher for searching edit text?

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: And the `EditText` comes from where exactly? The feature works in `ListView` without any `EditText` or `SearchView` (I've stated it already in the post), you just have to press keys in your keyboard and `adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint)` will be called automatically. If you use a `EditText` with a `TextWatcher`, it'll take the focus instead and pressing up/down buttons will not focus on the list items.